# Ackley optimization Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

Can anyone help me please with how should i do an optimaztion with Evolution Strategies for ackley function ?

Here i have the function:

```
function rez=ackley(x)
[m,d]=size(x);
sum1=0;
sum2=0;
for i=1:d
sum1=sum1+x(i)^2;
sum2=sum2+cos(2*pi*x(i));
end
rez=20+exp(1)-20*exp(-0.1*sqrt(sum1/d))-exp(sum2/d);
end
```

Comment: By optimization, do you mean runtime optimization?

Comment: yes..Evolution strategy (coincidence of 30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned "evolution strategy" in your comment to @Divkar, I am assuming you want to optmize the ackley function using any evolutionary algorithm.

In fact, if this is the case and if you are familiar with the [Particle Swarm Optimization (PSO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization) , there is a [submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41708-particle-swarm-optimization) (among many) in Matlab Exchange, that you can use. This one in particular, has the solution for the ackley function as a demo, which I write below:

```
%% function: demo function to show the effectivenees of pso in solving the ackley non-convex function
% editor: Yan Ou
% date: 20131205

function Demo
%% clear all
clear all; close all

%% set constant value
np = 200; % particle number
lb = -1; % lower boundary value
ub = 1; % upper boundary value

%% find the global minimum of the cost function
[xBest,yMin] = pso(@(x)ackley(x),np,lb,ub);

%% plot the result
x = -1:0.01:1;
y = ackley(x')';
figure(1);
hold on
plot(x,y);
h = plot(xBest,yMin,'gO','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',14);
legend(h,'Global Minimum');
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
title('Find the global minimum of ackley function using pso');

end
```

Comment: can you please to give an exemple about how should i call this function ?

Comment: You just need to download the submssion from the link I posted. Then you need to have all the 3 mfiles on your working folder or add the folder and run the demo. The pso algorithm is called, and as argument you pass the ackley function (function to be optimized), number of particles, lower an dupper boundaries, which are parameters from the particle swarm optimization algorithm. The code above was extraced from the demo file, the same you will have to run.

Comment: How did the function run? Were you able to optmize the Ackley function using the PSO algorithm? If you found this solution useful please consider accepting it as an answer